# Regex solution for www and non-www domain

Tags: regex, lighttpd, vhosts

I would like some help with this

Working code: regex to match xxx.domain.com

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^[^.]+\.domain\.com$" {
    evhost.path-pattern = vhosts_dir + "/company/domain.com/subdomains/%3/"
}
```

Www not working: (regex to match domain.com is working)

```
else $HTTP["host"] =~ "^([^.]+\.)?domain\.com$" {
 evhost.path-pattern = vhosts_dir + "/company/domain.com/public/"
}
```

How do I get www to work with the second code example?

^(^|www.)example.com$

Thanks

Magnus

Comment: What's the + after domain for in your first regexp? That would match domainnnnnn. Also, you've lost the anchor to the start of string ^ in the second example. These make me think you may have inadvertently made an error changing things for the Stackover flow question - could you check?

Comment: I´ve changed the code example now. Better?

Answer (score 0):

Just matching `\bdomain.com$` is probably good enough, unless you worry about "bogus-domain.com" showing up.  Then you could write `^(?:[^.]+\.)*domain\.com$`.

Have you canonicalized to lower case?

Comment: Thank you tchrist for the code to prevent bogus-domains. I never knew about that scenario.I´m a newbie, what do you mean by canonicalized to lower case?

Comment: ^(?:www|[^.]+\.)*domain\.com$

Comment: A bad example, but I hope you understand my thought.

Comment: If I change order of the two your solution works for www but then the code for subdomains doesn´t work. I´m stuck :(